# Почему срабатывает оператор приведения?

Tags: c++, ооп

я пишу класс matrix, для работы с двумерными массивами.
Есть следующие реализации:

```
//Функция копирования
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix& srcArr) {
    n = srcArr.n; m = srcArr.m;
    matrix = new double *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new double[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = srcArr.matrix[i][j];
}

//Деструктор матрицы
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[]matrix;
}    
//Умножение матриц
Matrix operator*(Matrix& matrix1, Matrix& matrix2) {
    if (matrix1.m == matrix2.n) {
        Matrix temp(matrix1.n, matrix2.m);
        double s;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.m; j++) {
                s = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < matrix1.m; k++)
                    s += matrix1.matrix[i][k] * matrix2.matrix[k][j];
                temp.matrix[i][j] = s;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else throw invalid_argument("Не совпадают размеры массивов");
}

Matrix::operator double() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            sum += matrix[i][j];
    return sum;
}

//Присваивание элементам матрицы значения 
void Matrix::operator=(double x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = x;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix srcArr) {
    this->~Matrix();
    n = srcArr.n; m = srcArr.m;

    matrix = new double *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new double[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = srcArr.matrix[i][j];

    return *this;
}
```

Выполняется следующее предложение:

```
Matr = Matr2 * Matr3;
```

Процесс выполнения:
Вызывается функция умножения(в ней вместе с `return temp` вызывается конструктор копирования и деструктор)
Умножение возвращает объект класса Matrix
Вдруг вызывается оператор приведения, который возвращает сумму
И так как вернулось число, то срабатывает оператор Matrix = double
Соответственно, вызов оператора double() все ломает.
В этом собственно и вопрос, почему он срабатывает?
Ведь умножение возвращает объект и предложение получается следующим Matr = {Matrix::Obj} и должна срабатывать функция Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix srcArr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать `Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix srcArr)`, компилятору нужно сначала вызвать конструктор для параметра.

`Matrix operator*(Matrix& matrix1, Matrix& matrix2)` возвращает временный объект (rvalue), но `Matrix::Matrix(Matrix& srcArr)` может работать только с 'не временными' объектами (lvalue), потому что вы использовали неконстантную ссылку.

Для константных ссылок такого ограничения нет. Используйте `Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& srcArr)`.

---

Также, стоит поменять параметры `operator*` на константные ссылки.

Также, `operator double()` лучше сделать константным: `operator double() const`. Желательно еще `explicit`, чтобы он не срабатывал в неожиданных ситуациях. (В идеале, вообще заменить его на обычный метод, какой-нибудь `.sum()`. Мне кажется так было бы понятнее.)

Также, оба `operator=` должны возвращать `Matrix &`.

Также, я бы убрал вызов деструктора `this->~Matrix()` из `operator=`. Деструктор - не просто метод. После вызова деструктора объект считается "уничтоженным", и попытка читать/писать в его поля вызывает неопределенное поведение (на практике это означает, что если включить оптимизацию, это место может "запутать" компилятор).

Вообще, `operator=(Matrix srcArr)` можно написать намного проще:

```cpp
Matrix &Matrix::operator=(Matrix other)
{
    std::swap(matrix, other.matrix);
    std::swap(n, other.n);
    std::swap(m, other.m);
    // Здесь нужно свапнуть все поля.
    return *this;
}
```

Это называется [copy & swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: Не зря советуют писать const везде, где это возможно). А чем вызвано ограничение что `Matrix::Matrix(Matrix& srcArr)` принимает только lvalue. Время жизни временного объекта не продлевается?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Просто язык так сделан. (Думаю в принципе ничего не мешало бы сделать так, чтобы можно было инициализировать неконстантые ссылки rvalue, и продлевать время жизни rvalue. Но для удобства решили это запретить.)